# Wait statement to be synthesizable

Tags: vhdl

I have this problem with the VHDL synthesis. I read in multiple articles that the "wait" statement is synthesizable if I only use one "wait until"/process, so that's what I did. So I tried to make a counter which shows at what floor I am (my project consists of an elevator in Logic Design), and it should open the doors for 5 seconds at floors which were ordered. The problem is with the wait statement. I don't know what to replace it to make it work in ISE too.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity counter is
    port(clk1: in std_logic;
    enable2:in std_logic;
    input_mux: in std_logic;
    dir: in std_logic;
    reset,s_g,s_u: in std_logic;
    q_open: out std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end counter;

architecture c1 of counter is 

signal flag: std_logic:='0';

component test 
port(clock: in std_logic;
a: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
notify: out std_logic);
end component;    

begin
delay: test port map(clk1,"0101",flag);
process
    variable temp:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    variable q_open_var:std_logic:='0';
    begin
    if (enable2='1') then
         if (s_g='1' and s_u='1') then 
             if (RESET='1') then 
                 temp:="0000";
             elsif (CLK1'EVENT and CLK1='1') then
                  if (DIR='1') then 
                      temp:=temp+1;
                  elsif(DIR='0') then 
                      temp:=temp-1;
                  end if;
             end if;
        end if;
    end if; 
    if (input_mux='1') then 
        q_open_var:='1';
        q_open<=q_open_var;
        wait until (flag'event and flag='1');
        q_open_var:='0';
    end if;
    q<=temp;
    q_open<=q_open_var;
wait on clk1, reset;
end process;
end c1;
```

Comment: XST.pdf, Ch. 14 XST VHDL Language Support, VHDL Sequential Circuits, [VHDL Sequential Process Without a Sensitivity List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugypl.jpg). Also see [VHDL Multiple Wait Statements Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eZ4i.jpg), noting support may vary by device family, Xilinx going through tool transitions leading up to Vivaldo.  Read The Fine Manual, show your error messages, provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't trust any articles in terms of what is supported for synthesis. You can only rely on documents from manufacturer of your device. Read what @user1155120 provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this structure is supported, you pushed over the limit of what is supported. The synthesis tool must generate registers from what you code. A register does have a clock and a reset input, but the synthesis tool does not know the words `clk1` and `reset`. I.e. is you write

```
wait on clk1, reset;
```

The tool will not know what the reset is, nor what the clock is. Actually, both signals are considered clock triggers.

But you design is more problematic, as you have if-statements before the asynchronous reset and clock trigger. Although clock-gating is supported, you probably did not intend it.

Then there is a /second/ clock trigger in you statement: `wait until (flag'event and flag='1');`. I don't know what you are doing there, but how would you imagine this being realized in hardware?

You should really stick to standard/advised coding style for predictable behavior. I.e.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

[...]
    signal temp : unsigned(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    temp_proc: process(clk1, reset)
        variable q_open_var : std_logic := '0';
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk1) then
        if enable2='1' and s_g='1' and s_u='1' then 
            if dir = '1' then
                temp <= temp + 1;
            elsif dir = '0' then
                temp <= temp - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    if reset = '1' then
        temp <= (others => '0');
    end if;
end process;

q <= std_logic_vector(temp);
```

(I left out the `q_open` part, as it is unclear what you want. Make a SEPARATE process for that, as it is not dependent on `reset`)

p.s. I like the five lines of `end if;` the most ;) Please use proper indenting next time. And use 'elsif' not 'else if'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for those "end if" lines haha. I wanted to make q_open be equal to '1' when input_mux is '1' for 5 clock pulses (synthesizable of course). How do I do that?

Comment: @AndreiBrașoveanu Two options: 1) introduce a "counter" that counts from 4 to 0: set `q_open <= '1'; count <= 4;` and then `if count = 0 then q_open <= '0'`. 2) use registers in a row to propagate a signal 5 clock pulses and combine that with a ser-reset flipflop.

Comment: I did that, it works fine. Although I can't get a D Flip-Flop content before it resets (because of the port maps I linked the signals). How can I delay the reset just by very few ns so I can use its content first? (synthesizable)

Comment: @AndreiBrașoveanu. Although sometimes possible (but difficult), you shouldn't do that, as that will screw up set-up and hold times. You should consider changing your design that the data does not get reset before you need it.